# duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppodealCircleTimer._font in

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, duplicate-symbol

I just updated a framework called Appodeal in my iOS codebase and have started seeing these duplicate symbol errors. I know that these errors usually show up when a framework is included twice in the build phases so I checked this and verified that it is only included once. The way I replaced the framework is deleted the old Appodeal.framework and then copied the new Appodeal.framework in project directory. I also cleaned the project and build folder after updating the framework.

The errors I am seeing are -

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppodealCircleTimer._font in:
    /Users/abc/Documents/Develop/IRCTC/Appodeal/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(AppodealCircleTimer-AC8FA416DBD204B8.o)
    /Users/abc/Documents/Develop/IRCTC/Appodeal/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(AppodealCircleTimer-FC164D706B975948.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppodealCircleTimer._offset in:
    /Users/abc/Documents/Develop/IRCTC/Appodeal/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(AppodealCircleTimer-AC8FA416DBD204B8.o)
    /Users/abc/Documents/Develop/IRCTC/Appodeal/Appodeal.framework/Appodeal(AppodealCircleTimer-FC164D706B975948.o)
```

Looking at the logs I am wondering why two object files are being created for `AppodealCircleTimer`. Can someone please help me figure out whats wrong here?

Comment: Did you add the same file to your project twice?

Comment: Nope the framework has been added to the project just once.

Comment: I suggest you clean and rebuild.If it doesn't work,remove that framework and redo.

Comment: I'd almost have to guess that the Appodeal framework is miscompiled -- sure looks like the same source file is included in there twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.
```

$(PROJECT_DIR)

Same worked for me some time ago, but guys from Appodeal have super speedy support, that is really helpful and nice. i reach them out any time on live chat from their homepage. @tbag try to ask them if this wont help